# Tiles Not Rendering While Put Inside Grid

Tags: sapui5

[image]I am trying to render StandardTile in a Grid, but due to some reason it's not working. however, it works when I remove the Grid & Panel from my code.
Can anyone point out what exactly am I doing wrong here?

```
    <mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout" xmlns="sap.m"
    controllerName="hanaDashBoard.controller.Home">
    <Page showHeader="false" enableScrolling="false">
        <Toolbar class="sapUiTinyMarginTop" id="toolbar1" height="10%">
            <ComboBox id="SidCombo" width="11.5%" showSecondaryValues="true"
                items="{
                    path: '/results'
                }" selectionChange="SidSelect">
                <core:ListItem key='{Key}' text='{Sid}'
                    additionalText='{Template}' />
            </ComboBox>
            <Text id="TemplateText"></Text>
            <Text id="SltText"></Text>
            <ToolbarSpacer />
            <Button id="UserName" icon="sap-icon://kpi-managing-my-area"
                enabled="false" type="Transparent" />
        </Toolbar>
        <l:Grid
        id="leGrid"
        class="sapUiSmallMarginTop"
        hSpacing="2"
        visible="false"
        >
        <l:content>
        <Panel width="auto" class="sapUiResponsiveMargin">
        <content>
                <TileContainer id="container"
                    width="100%" height="100%" visible="true" tileDelete="handleTileDelete"
                    tiles="{/TileCollection}">
                    <StandardTile icon="{icon}" type="{type}" number="{number}"
                        numberUnit="{numberUnit}" title="{title}" info="{info}"
                        infoState="{infoState}" press="handleTilepress" />
                </TileContainer>
        </content>
        <layoutData>
                    <l:GridData span="L12 M12 S12" />
        </layoutData>
        </Panel>
        </l:content>
        </l:Grid>
        <footer>
            <Toolbar>
                <ToolbarSpacer />
                <Button id="editbutton" text="Edit" press="tilePressed" />
                <ToolbarSpacer />
            </Toolbar>
        </footer>
    </Page>
</mvc:View>
```

Comment: Which grid and panel are you referring to?

Comment: My Bad, I uploaded the code without the Grid. I have updated my code now

Comment: Did you check the dev tools ? See if there are any others?

Comment: initially Grid's visibility is set to false, it is changed to true after selection is made from combobox, but I am getting a blank panel instead after combobox selection is made.

Comment: @Chris: I didn't understand, do you mean other grids? there's only this grid. I have checked developer tools, in "Element" section I can see only 1 tile's attributes. I'll try to add the screenshot here

Comment: I'm sorry, my fingers are independent of my brain sometimes. That was meant to be "
 
Did you check the dev tools ? See if there are any ERRORS?".

Comment: I did, no errors. it's just not rendering. no errors at all

Comment: Maybe put a debugger; statement in the method in your controller where you make the Grid visible. Very possibly something going wrong there.

Comment: no, when I make it visible I get a blank Panel